# ui-gmap-windows doesn't load templateUrl with no error

Tags: angularjs, angular-google-maps

I'm using angular-google-maps.
I need to use the templateUrl in ui-gmap-windows
with this simple code

```
<ui-gmap-windows show="'show'" templateUrl="'path/mycustom.html'"></ui-gmap-windows>
```

The problem is that the template isn't loaded and what is worse
I don't see any clue/error in firebug/chrome console (ie a 404 status) to see
if I made something wrong so I don't know which
way to turn :(

Do you have any idea ?

### UPDATE

I sort of worked  it out with ui-gmap-window
using the same logic

Comment: is request being made in dev tools network?

Comment: I dont see anything that's the hard point :(

Comment: it seems that no request has been made

Comment: did you succeed to figure it out - how to make it work? I have exact same issue

Comment: @shershen take a look at my update afak it's the only workaround